# Ember js -- validating file type

Tags: validation, ember.js

Is there a file type validation in Ember js. I've tried to find a validator - but only found more generic validators.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-validations

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-file-upload

I am looking to invoke a validator to check for particular accepted file types -- like pdf, ppt.

Comment: You that to do this reliable this is *extremely* hard? you basically need a parser for all accepted file types. However you can and should check the mime type / the file extension. All more complex checks should be done server side.

Comment: Are you trying to validate actual bytes (file format)?  Or just trying to check the file extension?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML patter for input file

```
<input accept="file_extension|audio/*|video/*|image/*|media_type">
```

Example:

```
<input accept=".ppt,.pdf">
```

More reference on
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp

Comment: does the input accept parameter just tweak the browser panel to show the file types that can be accepted